# Is there a way to assign various images based upon a ttk button state?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

I'm working with a GUI and I would like to set my ttk buttons up with various images depending on the state of the button.  For example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import PhotoImage, ttk

activeImage = PhotoImage(file="images/active.png")
disabledImage = PhotoImage(file="images/disabled.png")
normalImage = PhotoImage(file="images/normal.png")

button = ttk.Button(frame,\
                    activeimage=activeImage,\
                    disabledimage=disabledImage, \
                    normalimage=normalImage,\
                    command=lambda pass)
```

I'm not finding anything in the tk docs that explains how to do this, nor on this site.  My apologies if this has already been asked somewhere else.

Comment: I'm no OOP guru.  If anything I'm a hack.  But, could this be done through overloading?  Maybe switching the TButton.label.image dependent on the state of the button?  I don't have a concept in mind because I'm still learning OOP, but I recall somewhere that you can add extra functionality through inheritance and overloading.  Is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the ttk widgets support mapping attributes to states with the `map` method of a `Style`.

For example:

```
style = ttk.Style()
style.map(
    "Custom.TButton",
    image=[
        ("disabled", disabledImage),
        ("!disabled", normalImage),
        ("active", activeImage)
    ]
)
```

Next, create a button with this style:

```
button = ttk.Button(frame, style="Custom.TButton")
```

The tkdocs.com site has a nice tutorial on creating custom styles. See [Styles and Themes](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/styles.html)

Comment: I tried using "focus" so the image changes when the mouse moves over it because "active" did not cause a change on mouseover.  Otherwise, this works for the disabled and normal images.